# Combine two list views into one view in android

Tags: android, list, listview

how to combine two list views into one view in android.Both List Views have unique ids.If first_list id is present then it should be "ADD" button visible.If second_list id is present then it should be "Remove" button visible.Plz help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following class correspond to what you need ?

```
public class DoubleListView extends LinearLayout {

    private Button button;

    public final ListView list1, list2;

    public DoubleListView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setOrientation(VERTICAL);

        list1 = new ListView(context);
        addView(list1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));

        list2 = new ListView(context);
        addView(list2, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));

        button = new Button(context);
        addView(button, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // Initial state
        list2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        updateContent();
    }

    private void updateContent() {
        if(list2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            button.setText("REMOVE");
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    list2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    updateContent();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            button.setText("ADD");
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    list2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    updateContent();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

You can use it in a sample activity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DoubleListView dbleListView = new DoubleListView(this);
    dbleListView.list1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    dbleListView.list2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    setContentView(dbleListView);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this and also define the placement of the "child" views in xml?

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to combine two ListViews? Why you can do this on Cursor or Array level? Probably there is a possibility to do this but it sounds "dirty code".

Comment: not like that...one list contains FAVORITE teams,another list contains ALL teams.we have to display both in one list.Favorite row should contain REMOVE button whereas ALL row should contain ADD button.If click on ADD button it will add to your favorite team list.

Comment: You can achieve this by making your own custom adapter. Still no reason to merge two ListViews.

Comment: I am getting data through web-services in two lists(FAVRT and NON-FAVRT).I have display the both in one page.